# Deserializing transient fields with XStream 1.4.2

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream, xml-deserialization, transient

I've faced with a requirement to deserialize fields that possibly can be transient using XStream 1.4.2. Despite of that, such fields may be annotated with both `@XStreamAlias` and `@XStreamAsAttribute`. Yes, I know, it sounds weird, and this is an indicator of bad design, but this is what I currently have. Since XStream offers a way to specify custom converter, I tried to extend `com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter` in order to override the default way of omitting all transient fields trying to make XStream allow to deserialize them. However, I've fully stuck having two ideas to implement such a converter, but none of them works. So here is what I tried:

The 1st way doesn't work:

```java
public final class TransientSimpleConverter extends ReflectionConverter {

    private final Class<?> type;

    private TransientSimpleConverter(Class<?> type, Mapper mapper, ReflectionProvider reflectionProvider) {
        super(mapper, reflectionProvider);
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static TransientSimpleConverter transientSimpleConverter(Class<?> type, XStream xStream) {
        return new TransientSimpleConverter(type, xStream.getMapper(), xStream.getReflectionProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldUnmarshalTransientFields() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return this.type == type;
    }

}
```

The 2nd way doesn't work either:

```java
public final class TransientComplexConverter extends ReflectionConverter {

    private final Class<?> type;

    private TransientComplexConverter(Class<?> type, Mapper mapper, ReflectionProvider provider) {
        super(mapper, provider);
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static TransientComplexConverter transientComplexConverter(Class<?> type, Mapper mapper, Iterable<String> fieldNames) {
        return new TransientComplexConverter(type, mapper, TransientHackReflectionProvider.transientHackReflectionProvider(type, fieldNames));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return this.type == type;
    }

    private static final class TransientHackReflectionProvider extends PureJavaReflectionProvider {

        private final Class<?> type;
        private final Collection<Field> allowedFields;
        private final Collection<String> allowedAliases;

        private TransientHackReflectionProvider(Class<?> type, Collection<Field> allowedFields, Collection<String> allowedAliases) {
            this.type = type;
            this.allowedFields = allowedFields;
            this.allowedAliases = allowedAliases;
        }

        public static TransientHackReflectionProvider transientHackReflectionProvider(final Class<?> type, Iterable<String> fieldNames) {
            final Collection<Field> allowedFields = from(fieldNames).transform(new Function<String, Field>() {
                @Override
                public Field apply(String name) {
                    return field(type, name);
                }
            }).toList();
            final Collection<String> allowedAliases = transform(allowedFields, new Function<Field, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Field f) {
                    return f.getName();
                }
            });
            return new TransientHackReflectionProvider(type, allowedFields, allowedAliases);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean fieldModifiersSupported(Field field) {
            return allowedFields.contains(field) ? true : super.fieldModifiersSupported(field);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean fieldDefinedInClass(String fieldName, Class type) {
            return type == this.type && allowedAliases.contains(fieldName) ? true : super.fieldDefinedInClass(fieldName, type);
        }

        private static final Field field(Class<?> type, String name) {
            try {
                final Field field = type.getDeclaredField(name);
                checkArgument(isTransient(field.getModifiers()), name + " is not transient");
                checkArgument(field.getAnnotation(XStreamAsAttribute.class) != null, name + " must be annotated with XStreamAsAttribute");
                checkArgument(field.getAnnotation(XStreamAlias.class) != null, name + " must be annotated with XStreamAlias");
                return field;
            } catch (final SecurityException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            } catch (final NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestions or ideas for a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but maybe someone is still interested. My solution:

```java
XStream xstream = new XStream(new MyPureJavaReflectionProvider());

class MyPureJavaReflectionProvider extends PureJavaReflectionProvider {

    public MyPureJavaReflectionProvider() {
        this(new FieldDictionary(new ImmutableFieldKeySorter()));
    }

    public MyPureJavaReflectionProvider(FieldDictionary fieldDictionary) {
        super(fieldDictionary);
    }

    protected boolean fieldModifiersSupported(Field field) {
        int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
        return !Modifier.isStatic(modifiers);
    }

    public boolean fieldDefinedInClass(String fieldName, Class type) {
        Field field = fieldDictionary.fieldOrNull(type, fieldName, null);
        return field != null && fieldModifiersSupported(field);
    }   

}
```

Comment: It's almost 3 years past since I no longer work with that weird project, and cannot check your solution unfortunately, but thank you for the input being the first person to answer it anyway.